# How to get variable value outside a function IN jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable i assign value to it inside a function now i want to get this value outside of this variable but i get undefined, below is my code. I have select2 on my page whcih i want to populate with some data depend on what users choices are, i allow a user to choose a radio button and i get the value of the radio button to determine which data to display in the select menu. Now after my coding i could alert `var size_data` within the onclick event function but couldn't get this value to the select2 where i need it, any help on this will be appreciated

**Note** `var size_data` is a global variable and the variable that holds different sizes are also global variable

see my [DEMO ON FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sammyzeal/nnaL44ur/3/)

```
var uk_size = [{ id: '8', text: '8' },
                { id: '10', text: '10' }, 
                { id: '12', text: '12' },
            ];
var us_size = [{ id: '4', text: '4' },
                { id: '6', text: '6' }, 
                { id: '8', text: '8' },
                { id: '10', text: '10' }, 
            ];
var eu_size = [{ id: '34', text: '34' },
                { id: '36', text: '36' }, 
                { id: '38', text: '38' },
            ];
var ng_size = [{ id: 'XS', text: 'XS' },
                { id: 'S', text: 'S' }, 
                { id: 'M', text: 'M' },
            ];
var size_data = ng_size; //default value;
//alert(ng_size);
   $("#size-style input:radio").on('click',function() {
              //alert(ng_size);

                  var size_style ="";
                size_style = $(this).val();
                if (size_style === "ng-size"){
                      size_data = ng_size;  
                }else if(size_style === "uk-size"){
                      size_data = uk_size; 
                }else if(size_style === "us-size"){
                      size_data = us_size;
                }else{
                    size_data = eu_size;
                }
                alert(size_data);//can alert jquery object here
    });



$('select.size-select').select2({
        name: 'size',
        value: 'S',
        data: size_data,
        tags: "true",
        placeholder: "Select size",
        allowClear: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the `select2` with default value first and then in radio button click event you can modify its data like below:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/nnaL44ur/4/

```
$("#size-style input:radio").on('click', function() {
  //alert(ng_size);

  var size_style = "";
  size_style = $(this).val();
  if (size_style === "ng-size") {
    size_data = ng_size;
  } else if (size_style === "uk-size") {
    size_data = uk_size;
  } else if (size_style === "us-size") {
    size_data = us_size;
  } else {
    size_data = eu_size;
  }
  alert(size_data); //can alert jquery object here

  var $select = $('select.size-select'); //grabbing the select element

  //fetching the previously set options at the first time initialization of select2 widget
  var options = $select.data('select2').options.options;

  $select.html(''); //clearing the previous dropdown options
  // add new items to the options
  options.data = size_data;
  $select.select2(options); //updating the select2 widget with newer set of option data

});
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: I did what u said but it seem not working it's not updating the data after click event happen, here is a fiddle i created https://fiddle.jshell.net/sammyzeal/nnaL44ur/3/

Comment: thanks so much this really works great, appreciate taking your time to help me out, though i can't understand the later part of the code. i will be glad if u can explain to me. thanks

Comment: @sam - i have tried adding few comments in above code by which you will be able to understand which all things are happening on your radio button click event. Hope these are clear. Please let me know if any of step is unclear to you.